# jQuery not selector not working on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to alert when someone clicks td element but I don't want to fire an event when someone clicks the button. How can I achieve this?

```js
$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr:not(button)', function () {
    alert('Hello world!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="example">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>
                <button type="button">Example</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I want to alert when someone  ?

Comment: Please review your phrasing of the question. It is not understandable.

Comment: Your selector is not logical. You select `<tr>` that is `not <button>`. Only one tag can be applied at once. Maybe when clicking on button just stop bubbling/propagation?

Comment: Would you tell me when the alert message popup?
Which condition(s) need(s) to be fullfill?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good option is to use `stopPropagation()` for button clicks. This way the click still happens, but it doesn't "bubble" up and isn't triggered for the `tr`:

```js
$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    alert('Hello world!');
});
$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'button', function (ev) {
    ev.stopPropagation()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="example">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>
                <button type="button">Example</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

Another option is to change the target element from `tr` to `td`, and choose only table cells that do not contain buttons:

```
$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'td:not(:has(button))', function () {
    alert('Hello world!');
});
```

This option isn't as good - it makes the clickable area smaller, it doesn't include the rest of the cell outside of the button, or the margin between cells.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stopPropagation()` method on the click event of the button to exclude the button from displaying the alert. I have given an id to the button.

```js
$('#example tbody').on( 'click', function () {
    alert('Hello world!');
    $('#myButton').on('click', function(e){
       e.stopPropagation(); 
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="example">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" id="myButton">Example</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('tr').click(function(){
   alert('beep');
});
```

and for button you could do

```
$('tr button').click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $('#example tbody').on( 'click','td',function (){
        alert('Hello world!');
 });
 $('button').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table id="example">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button">Example</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```